# Qt avoiding circular dependency

Tags: c++, qt, callback, circular-dependency

I have a Qt application with a main class GUIApplication which inherits from QMainWindow as shown below. The GUI has a start button, stop button and a QGraphicsScene.

My application will read data from the serial port and other stuff and draw on the QGraphicsScene according to what is received.

My main GUI class knows about my serial port class as it must initialse it on press of the start button etc. That is fine. My serial port class however must also must be able to communicate with my GUI class as it must update the QGraphicsScene on reception of data and other stuff.

My question is , is it a bad design for my serial port class to know about the GUI class also. Isn't this a form of circular dependency between the two classes? I plan to have a member of my serial port class a pointer to the GUI class. Is this the only way to do it , or should I register a callback in the serial port class instead, to decouple the classes? Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
// GUI class
#include "MySerial.h "
class GUIApplication : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
//.........
```

o_o

```
// Serial port class
#include "GUIApp.h "
class MySerial
{

public:
//..............
//write something on GUI`
```

Comment: Probably off topic but... any particular reason you don't just use [`QSerialPort`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) and have your GUI element(s) connect to the appropriate signals?

Comment: Off topic. Will need to update the GUI from other classes also . I shouldn't have mentioned serial port.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad design. Your serial port class has nothing to do with GUI by nature and as such should be separated from it - apart from circular dependencies, you make it much less flexible that way and limit its usability. One day you might want to use it in a console application and if you wrote the class in such a way that it must be aware of the GUI class, you would have to modify it just to make it work with console and either have two versions that would differ only regarding UI, which doesn't make much sense, or add Qt as dependency even though you would not need it in console app if you wouldn't want to break the compatibility, which doesn't make much sense either.

Much better solution is sending some signal from your serial port class or some meaningful return code after the data is received, and then make the GUI class catch this value and update QGraphicsScene itself. That way you also get rid off the circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks. In order to make the GUI code catch it, it would mean either the GUI code must either poll the serial port class , or else use a callback ? Is it possible to register a callback function belonging to my GUI class to the serial port class? Would that be the best option?

Comment: No problem. I guess the simplest solution is to make your serial port class a q_object, then connect its signal to a slot of GUI class. Polling is also a viable option. Hard to tell which one is better for you as it depends on what your program exactly does and what your requirements are. I would refrain from using callback here as callback is not that flexible since it would have to take a pointer to your GUI class as a parameter, because you would be registering a member function.

Comment: I've went with the callback method using standard C++11 constructs std::function and std::bind . I can now register a callback function to my serial port class which calls back a GUI function. My serial port class is not dependant at all on the GUI class as any function which takes two strings in my case can be registered. Using std::bind in my GUI class allows me to bind the GUI member function to register the callback in the serial port class.

Comment: I'm glad that it's worked for you. Thanks for the information regarding the solution that you've chosen.

Comment: Actually this method didn't work for me in the end. On trying to call the GUI callback from my other class, the program crashes with an error "qt cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread". Polling may be the best option